# How to make simple templating?

Tags: php, templates

NOTICE: This is about plain PHP and I am trying to replicate what Laravel does with the Blade templating engine, but in a much simpler and trivial way.

If I make a simple layout in `layout.php` like this:

Notice the variable for pageTitle and where the content should be displayed

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><?php $pageTitle ?? ''; ?></title>
</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

    HERE I WANT TO LOAD MY CONTENT

</body>
</html>
```

What I can't understand is how to "drop in" the content and show the pageTitle when I want to show a simple page that uses this layout. For example:

```
<?php require(app_views_path().'/layouts/app.view.php'); ?>
<?php $pageTitle = 'Welcome'; ?>

    <h1>Welcome Page</h1>
```

and now this  tag should be included and the `$pageTitle` variable set when page is opened.

How to produce this scenario?

What I have managed on my own is to just wrap around the page content and split the layout to _head and _foot part so it looks like this:

```
<?php require(app_views_path().'/layouts/_partials/_head.view.php'); ?>

    <h1>Welcome Page</h1>

<?php require(app_views_path().'/layouts/_partials/_foot.view.php'); ?>
```

But the `$pageTitle` I don't know how to set it because it gets rendered before the page content and I don't want to send the page title through the controller (that would be an anti pattern).

Comment: You need to define `<?php $pageTitle = 'Welcome'; ?>` before the `require`.

Comment: Set this `<?php $pageTitle = 'Welcome'; ?>` then require the page that contains this `<title><?php $pageTitle ?? ''; ?></title>` - think of include/require as cutting and pasting that code from the file, in that spot.  So if you pasted that, you would not set the title at the end would you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest wrapping this in a function.

```
<?php
function load_view($view, $data = []) {
    extract($data);
    require(app_views_path() . $view . ".view.php");
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
data = ["pageTitle" => "Welcome"];
load_view("layouts/app", $data);
```

Then in your view, you'll also need to echo something, which your original was not:

```
<title><?=$pageTitle ?? ''?></title>
```

Comment: Hmm this fixes getting the data from controller to the view... but my problem is the content that should be loaded like in Laravel with @yield
Maybe you know how to overcome this? For example when page is loaded with return view_load('some_template'); I want to avoid that "sendwich" what I have in my question (HEAD| Content | FOOT). I hope you understand me.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Might be worth opening another question to focus on that part of it.

Comment: How does laravel do this `$__env->startSection('content')`
I can't find this function startSection() nor stopSection()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302990/in-which-file-are-these-blade-functions-startsection-and-stopsection