# In which Class are these 'blade functions' startSection() and stopSection()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

When you open the cached view inside `storage/framework/views/`, there are rendered blade views and I can't find these functions:

```
$__env->startSection('content');
```

and

```
$__env->stopSection();
```

It's probably made with call_user_func() so you can't get to it just by clicking Ctrl+Click, this needs to be answered by someone who really knows the guts of Laravel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find these methods in the traits used on the `Illuminate\View\Factory` class.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php#L17-L23

This specific method is actually on the `Illuminate\Views\Concerns\ManagesLayouts` trait.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/View/Concerns/ManagesLayouts.php

Also, in the constructor of that class you will see that `$__env` is shared with the view.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php#L99